# how to increase number of threads used to compile C++ project in Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: visual-studio

While compiling C++ Unreal project VS 2022 write that max parallel compile is 6. How to increase that ? I have 16 threads. I can only find how to set the maxmium from tools|options|projects and solutions|VC++ project settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is the option value you need to change:

[image: Visual Studio 2022 - Maximum Concurrent C++ Compilations]

Comment: Thanks I left it at 0 mean all CPU cores utilized.